# Js script crashing entire element

Tags: javascript, html, embed, google-sites-2016

I am making a site on google sites.
I have a button made by code that detects if you put a certain value into an input box, it should then load another site. But when I enter that correct value, the object crashes.

I've tried a lot of different things, but nothing works.

```html
<form name="form1" method="GET">
    <input name="codebox1" type="text" />
    <input name="button1" type="submit" value="Check Code" onClick="return testResults(this.form)"/>
</form>

<script>
function testResults (form) {
    if (form.codebox1.value == "Doovhhlqjhbh") {
        window.location = 'https://sites.google.com/view/the-mbd-project/There-are-secrets-to-be-discovered';
        window.alert("Correct Code. Connecting...");
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Wrong Code, try again!");
    }  
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Mahdi Najafi it opens a new page but it doesn't load anything and gives me this error: 

Uncaught ReferenceError: testResults is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (inner-frame-minified.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.lb.pl.ZIZnN-TYlZI.O%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAHpOoo9dFmULJc4Qn3-3CIRmSC9ZDRB7Jg%2Fm%3D__features__:1:198)
onclick @ inner-frame-minified.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.lb.pl.ZIZnN-TYlZI.O%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAHpOoo9dFmULJc4Qn3-3CIRmSC9ZDRB7Jg%2Fm%3D__features__:1

Answer (score -2):

`window.location = string;` is wrong . You should use this to change the browser address. Also, `alert` must be executed before switching the page

change your function to this:

```
function testResults(form) {
    if (form.codebox1.value == "Doovhhlqjhbh") {
        window.alert("Correct Code. Connecting...");
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = 'https://sites.google.com/view/the-mbd-project/There-are-secrets-to-be-discovered';
        }, 0);
    }
    else { window.alert("Wrong Code, try again!"); } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add some comments or text explaining what you changed and why.

Comment: Also you should test this in Google new Sites.